# When do hours start when viewing visitors by hour in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

When I use Google Analytics to view my website visitors by hour, when does the hour start and finish?

For example, if Google Analytics tells me that I have 17 visitors at 14:00, does that mean I have 17 visitors between 1300 and 1400, or between 14:00 and 15:00, or between 13:30 and 14:30?

Answer (score 3):

When I view a graph of a single day by hour the first data point is 00:00 and the last is 23:00.  Since the day start and ends at midnight, that would indicate that time they indicate for the hour is the *starting time*.

So in your example 17 visitors at 14:00 would be the visitors from 14:00:00 to 14:59:59.

[image]